# docker compose file, set keys from environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use environment variables in my docker compose file, with docker stack. When I to use an environment variable like this, it works:

```yaml
services:
  service_test01:
    networks:
      - ${network}
    # more options here...
networks:
  some_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

However, if I try to use `${network}` instead of `some_network` in the networks (root) section:

```yaml
services:
  service_test01:
    networks:
      - ${network}
    # more options here...
networks:
  ${network}:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

Then it does not work, `docker stack config` shows that the generated config does nothing with `${network}` key, it leaves as it is.

Am I doing this the wrong way? Or maybe it is simply not supported? That would be very disappointing, and counter-intuitive. What is the point of being able to give networks with env vars under "/service/<service_name>/networks", but not allowing to define them under "/networks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this as you describe.  The [Compose Specification documentation on interpolation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/12-interpolation/) notes:

> Interpolation applies only to YAML values, not to keys.

It notes an alternate syntax that can be used for `environment:` and `labels:`, but this can't be used for `networks:`.

The per-Compose-file network name is one of several things that it doesn't really make sense to parameterize.  The network name is specific to a Compose file and there's no overlap with other Compose files, and no risk of conflicts.  If you let Compose create the network, the network name will be constructed using the Compose project name, and again, there is little risk of conflict.  It's safe to pick a single fixed name across the Compose file.

```yaml
# Picking a fixed name is safe:
networks:
  some_network: { ... }
services:
  service_test01:
    networks: [some_network]
```

If you're going to pick a fixed name and there's no risk of conflict, `default` can be a good name to pick.  As noted in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), Compose automatically creates the `default` network and automatically connects containers to it.  It's pretty unusual to need multiple Docker-internal networks, and for most applications the best setup is to have no `networks:` blocks at all.

```yaml
# Probably right for most applications:
# No top-level networks: block
services:
  service_test01:
    # No per-service networks: block
```

You can [customize the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) if you need non-default settings, and this might match your specific use case.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
services:
  service_test01:
    # no per-service networks: block
    # implies networks: [default]
```

The variable interpolation applies to pretty much every value.  In a couple of places this is confusing (in `command:` for example) or non-sensical (as you're noting for `networks:` names).  The flip side of this is that there are consistent rules for what syntax is understood: there aren't different interpolation rules for different Compose directives.

Comment: (I also would not parameterize container-side paths or container-process port numbers. These apply a little more to Dockerfiles, but in a Compose file, the right-hand sides of `volumes:` and `ports:` should usually be fixed values.)